# Connect to cloud SQL using Cloud SQL Auth is none resposinve in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

Im trying to create a connection for my SQL instance in GCP following their guide:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

I set up the proxy running but I cant connect to my server.
I use MySQL workbench and the connection just timeout.

I went trough the trouble shoot guide and could not find the issue.

- No errors in the cloud logs.
- I try to connect using the owner google account of the project (I have all the permissions).
- Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled.
- I entered the password in the menu.

I saw another [google guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-ip?hl=zh-TW#install-mysql-client) telling to white list your IP.
I did this and its the same error.

It seems like there is a firewall or something is blocking from GCP to connect to the server but Im not sure what.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding your Workbench machine's IP address as an [authorized network](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks#authorized-networks) for your Cloud SQL instance is much easier to connect than using Cloud SQL Auth Proxy. Have you seen this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-tools#workbench).

Comment: You're connecting to a MySQL instance with user postgres? Is there a mistake there?

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
Indeed I changed to authorized networkand to postgres client (pgAdmin 4) and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was:
Use Cloud SQL authorized network as JM Gelilio suggested and to use pgAdmin 4 for Postgres connections.